# Can't move sprites connected by joints to the right location

Tags: ios, physics, sprite-kit

I have a marionette connected by SKPhysicsJoints. I want it to behave so when I touch a certain point in the scene, the marionette's head moves to that point. Problem is, when I do it, the head moves TOWARDS that point, but does not reach it. If I keep clicking the same point, it will get a bit closer each time.

I have set affectedByGravity=NO on all the SKSpriteNodes that make up the marionette.

I am moving the sprite just by doing

```
head.position = (the position of the mouse)
```

and it works fine as long as the head isn't connected to the rest of the marionette by a joint.

So it's kind of like the rest of the sprites are weighing down the head. I wish I knew more about this, theres just so little info on Sprite Kit and not a lot handles this, from what I can find.

edit: Since I was asked, here is a sample project that demonstrates the problem I am having:

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
self.physicsWorld.speed = 1;
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

_head = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"head.png"];
_chest = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"chest_neck.png"];

_head.position = CGPointMake(512, 380);
_chest.position = CGPointMake(512, 290);

_head.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_head.size];
_head.physicsBody.mass = 1;
_head.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

_chest.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_chest.size];
_chest.physicsBody.mass = 1;
_chest.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

[self addChild:_head];
[self addChild:_chest];

CGPoint chestJointPinAnchor = CGPointMake(_chest.position.x, _chest.position.y+39);
SKPhysicsJointPin *chestJointPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:_head.physicsBody bodyB:_chest.physicsBody anchor:chestJointPinAnchor];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:chestJointPin];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

_head.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
_chest.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
_head.position = positionInScene;
}
```

Comment: can we see your marionette code? and is it a sub-class of a SKSpriteNode?

Comment: I added some code that should demonstrate it. Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1):

Just set your head to: `_head.physicsBody.dynamic = NO`, while the chest remains dynamic: `_chest.physicsBody.dynamic = YES`. 
You'll find the head now moves exactly to the touch location, dragging the chest along.